# stripping unneeded symbols from a static library

Tags: linux, static-libraries

I have a set of absolutely massive .a files from a third party. I have my own library that calls just 5 or 6 functions from this set of libraries. I would like to produce a much smaller .a file that includes my code and its (small number of) dependencies in the external library.

To be concrete:

### What I Have

1. external.h

   ```
   int foo();
   int bar();
   ```
2. libexternal.a

   ```
   0000000000000000 T foo()
   0000000000000010 T bar()
   ```
3. mylibrary.c

   ```
   #include "external.h"
   int foo_wrapper() { return foo(); }
   ```
4. mylibrary.h

   ```
   int foo_wrapper();
   ```

### What I want

I want to create a file `libmylibrary.a` that has the symbols for `foo_wrapper`, its dependency `foo`, and anything that `foo` calls internally, but not `bar` (which actually represents thousands of functions). This way, people could include my library without having to include `external.h` or link in `libexternal.a`. I am not willing to manually list `foo` because there are actually a whole bunch of functions.

Can it be done?

### More Detail

I'm willing to list the symbols of mine that I need. So for example, I'm ok with specifying `foo_wrapper` on the command line. But I'm not ok also specifying `foo` on the command line, as well as whatever functions it calls. The reason I'm ok specifying `foo_wrapper` is that it allows me to write one function called `callEverything()` that just calls all of the functions I want to make available, and then put that symbol on the command line.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: yes, but not in a way that satisfies your conditions.

Comment: As close as the answer posted below, AFAIK.

Comment: creating a library is not the same as creating an executable - the linker doesn't try to satisfy any external symbols for example and this is the step you want to occur.

Comment: Is there a hack where I make an executable that calls the function, and then read the list of symbols in the executable to figure out what to include in the new archive?

Comment: I'm now faced with the same problem myself.  Did you make any progress on this issue?  The "answers" presented below are completely unworkable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like KevinDTimm said: You can edit your .a file using "ar" to extract all the object files inside it and to add the necessary ones back to the .a archive.

The author of the library could have put all his functions into a single .c files or in multiple files. Each .c file results in one object file.

I think you have no chance to only take a part of the object file, you need all of it or nothing. At link time it's too late to separate a .obj file again into it's functions: There are too many directly embedded addresses and function calls.

Also your final program will contain a subset of the obj files that are "archived" into your linked .a static libraries. But each single obj file is either in your final exectuable completely or not at all!

Comment: "I think you have no chance to only take a part of the object file, you need all of it or nothing."  Are you sure that this statement is true? Do you have any documentation for it?

Comment: I did not find a convincing, good article for it.But search for "translation unit". As far as I know, traiditionally it's just impossible to rip apart an .o file:It contains any amount of compiled internal pointers to other parts of itself, no compiler can untangle it. All INTERNAL (to the .o-file) symbols are gone. BUT there are things like "whole programm optimization" in Visual Studio where the obj file basically contains source code or lexed stuff of it. The linker will do the actual compiling in that case.THEN it's possible for the linker to omit unneeded parts of single translation units

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `ar`, the archive program for *nix;

for all of your needs see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/ar-command-examples/) (or just type `man ar`)

short answer though, you're looking for the 't' option to view, the 'x' option to extract objects from the library and the 'r' option option to add them.

Note that that there may (will) be a multitude of interdependencies that will take quite some time to determine.

Comment: I certainly know about `ar`, but this doesn't solve my problem at all.  I'm trying to get the compiler/linker to deduce the set of used/unused symbols and give me an archive devoid of unnecessary symbols.

Comment: No, the job of the linker is only to find the symbols in the library that are needed and then link them to your executable.  If you're creating a library, you have to do it by hand.

Comment: But this isn't an answer at all.  The idea that each time you make changes to your code, you potentially need to go in *by hand* and figure out which symbols you might be using in a large library is simply madness.  Would you take that job?

Comment: There is no reason to do this besides the `desire` of the OP. If you wanted a new lawn, would you transplant one blade of grass at a time or lay sod?  (Or, at least, broadcast seed over the area)